# How to change the direction in which a menu is displayed?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I don't know if this is possible... but I want to change the direction  in which a menu is diplayed

I search in API and I don't find anything... some ideas??

[image: change direction of menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your picture, I think you rather mean that you want to change on which side of the 'menu starter' widget the menu is displayed (left vs right)? A menu “direction” would rather refer to order in which its items are displayed (top to bottom or *vice-versa*)

In any case, side or direction, you cannot control this from py script, this is handled by internal UI code (based on several factors like type of menu, position, available area on top/bottom/left/right, etc.).